# asp.net Panel DefaultButton property not working in Android Browser?

Tags: asp.net, .net, android-browser

clicking go button in android keyboard does not firing Default button. This works in iPhone

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="SubmitPanel" DefaultButton="Submit">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click">
         Submit
    </asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is the same issue that you're experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033/asp-net-form-defaultbutton-error-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Only Button and ImageButton controls are supported.  [The LinkButton is not supported.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the textbox or text input object that has focus (this is required for your android keyboard to be active) is wrapped inside this Submit Panel.

Comment: In the future, statements like this should probably be a comment and not a answer.

Comment: With all due respect, not only am I trying to help out but also perhaps get rep. points so that I can vote up all of the great answers on here.  I'll keep that in mind though.  Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        btnSubmit_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```